# HOG vector contains negative values

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm working with hog to extract image features, and i got negative values. I'm wondering is it normal that the Hog's vector contains negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is definitely not normal.  You are creating a histogram where the bins are the orientations of the gradient values and what gets binned are the magnitudes of the gradient.  Histograms should never have negative values as you are counting the occurrence of values.  In this case, you are accumulating gradient values so that get mapped into certain bins.  Gradient magnitudes by definition are not negative and so your histograms should never contain negative values.

You are most likely doing modifying the HOG descriptor after it was computed which results in negative values.

Comment: My pleasure! It you can later, please share your code so we can determine what's wrong.